# my js is not redirecting when the password is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this code works kinda but it opens another webpage up and leaves the login screen up. I have tried window.location.href, window.location.replace ,window.location="", none of it works. I would love for it to work in one tab but the open window is the only thing working. please help me.

```
<html>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return checkPswd()">
        <input id="user" type="text" name="username" 
placeholder="username">
        <input id="pass" type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" 
onclick="checkPswd();" onkeydown="checkPswd()">
</form>    
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">  
       function checkPswd(){
        var confirmpassword = "admin";
        var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;

            if(password == confirmpassword){

                window.open('redu.html') 

            }else{
                alert('try again');
            }

        }



</script>    

</html>
```

Comment: `window.location = "redu.html";` should work. Are you getting any error when using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling checkPswd onsubmit, onkeydown, and onclick, and after that you you are actually submitting a form which is meant to redirect to another url. Make up your mind where do you want to call the checkPswd?

On a side note: Are you really storing the password in javascript variable? which can be viewed by everyone (right-click on page and view source).

Assuming you want to continue with checking password in javascript do the following to fix your issue:

1. Remove the onsubmit from Form tag.
2. Remove the onkeydown event.
3. Change type of input field from "submit" to "button"

And don't use window.open() because that opens a new window, leaving the current one opened as it is.

use window.location.href = "redu.html";

This will not submit the form (hence redirect) and will only checkPswd on click of button.

Comment: the reason I added the onkeydown was for the enter button to also trigger the function. So you think I should still take it out

Comment: there is no onkeydown event of a button. only a text input or similars have a keydown event where you actually press a key while in focus. you would have to do the document.onkeydown = checkPswd(); to capture the enter key but that will trigger with every key entry, not just enter.